# PHP Interpreter of PHP container running inside a Virtual Machine

Tags: php, docker, containers, vagrant, phpstorm

I have a php project using a virtual machine. PHP is running as a container inside the Virtual machine (don't ask me why). I am using PhpStorm as IDE and want to configure the PHP interpreter.

So if anyone has already been through such a setup I would appreciate his help

Comment: So what ... you are running Docker inside the Vagrant?

Comment: Exactly. This is the first time I see such a setup

Comment: TBH: do not know. The only thing that comes into my mind right now is "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS " option and have that port available/forwarded in Vagrant so PhpStorm can connect inside the VM... But I still believe that IDE wants some local Docker executables to be available (not mega sure though)

Comment: Better contact PhpStorm Support on this -- they know better how their tool works and what can be done here.

Comment: Can you run a local development environment without involving the VM/container, using a non-container PHP installation, and then `docker build` an image when you need to test it in the deployment environment?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work: PhpStorm relies on path mappings & helper scripts for remote (vagrant/docker) php interpreters. In your case this would involve double mappings & double helpers - that's not supported unfortunately.

Comment: The same on PhpStorm Forums, it has some suggestion there: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010237140-PHP-Interpreter-from-docker-running-inside-a-VM-Vagrant